# How to combine 2 variables into 1 line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following variables and I am trying to combine two lines for each variables into one. I know this is a rookie questions so am I, in JS.

```
 var entry;
 var average;
 var total = 0;
        

 entry = prompt("Enter test score");
 ******entry = parseInt(entry);
 var score1 = entry;******
 total = total + score1;
```

How would one combine these highlighted two line of codes into one line of code?

Comment: Something like `var score1 = parseInt (entry);`?

Comment: Do you want entry to be parsed and restored as itself, as well? in that case it needs to be two lines of code. otherwise the below (and above) answers are correct.

Comment: Just put them in the same line, there is no multi assignment in JavaScript like C,C++

Comment: Are you using parseInt to confirm that the users input is a numerical score and not a string?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes that's the reason I am using parseInt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you parse a variable then assign value to another. So you can just do

```
var score1 = parseInt(entry)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you Roberto. Tesekkurler Cagatay! Great work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const score1 = parseInt(entry);
```

I believe that is what you want.

Comment: It's not the same though.

Comment: Hmm, not sure exactly how it's different. I am using const instead of var though.

Comment: It's not technically the same, let's assume in the Ops question  entry was a string, after execution entry and  score1 are now numbers, here entry will still be a string.  It's maybe fine for what the OP requires, but worth pointing out the results are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you have a misunderstanding in the code above, When you declared `var score1 = entry` Now score1 equals the entry therefore a 2 code line will be:

```
var score1 = entry
var integer-entry = parseInt(score1) // Not parseInt(entry) again as it defeats the purpose of line 1
```

Regarding your question a one line solution will be:

```
// ES5 variable version
var score1 = parseInt(entry)

//ES6 variable version
let score1 = parseInt(entry)

//ES6 constant version (assign a constant if it wont change)
const score1 = parseInt(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess, I should have given more details. The whole line of the code is as follows.

```
     var entry;
     var average;
     var total = 0;
            
   
     entry = prompt("Enter test score");
     ******entry = parseInt(entry);
     var score1 = entry;******
     total = total + score1;
```

In this code, I am trying to combine the highlighted lines into one line.

Comment: you should have edited your original post with this information.

Comment: If the var entry is not required anywhere else you could just do `total += parseInt(prompt("Enter test score"), 10)`. Ps. The `,10` is deliberate, you should really supply a raddix for parseInt.